# Finding different roots of an equation

Tags: equation-solving

I have an equation and I want to solve it with FindRoot but is there any way to give a range to FindRoot instead of giving a point?
this is my MMA code:

```
uvariable3 = 
u /. FindRoot[(1/(1/u^2 + 1/(v^2 - u^2)))*((
    BesselJ[m - 1, u] - BesselJ[m + 1, u])/(
    2*u*BesselJ[m, 
      u]) + (BesselK[m - 1, Sqrt[v^2 - u^2]] + 
       BesselK[m + 1, Sqrt[v^2 - u^2]])/(-2*Sqrt[v^2 - u^2]*
       BesselK[m, u]))*((BesselJ[m - 1, u] - BesselJ[m + 1, u])/(
    2*u*BesselJ[m, 
      u]) + ((n2/
       n1)^2*((BesselK[m - 1, Sqrt[v^2 - u^2]] + 
          BesselK[m + 1, Sqrt[v^2 - u^2]])/(-2*Sqrt[v^2 - u^2]*
          BesselK[m, u])))) - m^2/u^2 == 
   m^2*((n2/n1)^2*1/(v^2 - u^2)), {u, 1.5}]
```

and u is the only variable. I have the value for other variables.

Comment: Try [`NSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve.html): `NSolve[{f[x] == g[x], xmin <= x <= xmax}, x]`. If appropriate, you can also restrict the domain.

Comment: Actually, NSolve does not give me any root. so I plotted the rhs and lhs and then by using this plot I give a point too FindRoot to find the root but I have more than one root and so I have to change the starting point to find all the roots

Comment: `Map` `FindRoot` onto a list of starting points taken from the `Plot`: `FindRoot[f[x] == g[x], {x, #}] & /@ pts`

Comment: Why didn't you publish your equation as MMA code?

Comment: Do you already know how `FindRoot` works (Newton's method) and *why* it gives you a single root only?

Comment: Try `NSolve[{Eq(r) == 0,r_Min <= r <= r_Max},r]`

Comment: @Mehrab I tried it before but NSolve did not give me answer

Comment: @ Szabolcs actually no because I've just started learning Matemathica

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann I added it to my question thank you

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation

> ```
> FindRoot[lhs==rhs,{x, x_start,  x_min, x_max}]
> ```
>
> searches for a solution, stopping the search if x ever gets outside the range [x_min,x_max]

Have you tried this?

Comment: I tried it but it gave me exactly the x_start as the root of my equation

Comment: Are you sure your function has a root in the range provided? If not, you can try and implement a method to extend the range until a root is found or try a different algorithm.

Comment: yes I'm sure because I made the plot of f==g and there are some intersections